# Passing in template class reference as parameter in c++

Tags: c++, templates

So I have something like:

```
template<int X>
class foo {

char a[X];

...

}
```

and I have another class 'bar' which contains a function like:

```
void execute(foo &b);
```

which should perform tasks on the char array in foo but it gives me an error saying it's a template class but using something like:

```
void execute(foo<int> &b);
```

gives an error as well. I'm not sure how exactly to pass it as the only thing which doesn't give me an error is if I statically give it a value like:

```
void execute(foo<4> &b);
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Non-type template parameters should be known at compile-time.
Right call for function will be something like

```
template<int N>
void execute(foo<N>& b);

// call
foo<4> b;
execute(b);
```